# Google Script ModalDialog/ ModelessDialog setWidth and setHeight feature not working

Tags: google-apps-script

The code below creates a Modeless Dialog with static dimensions. The setWidth and setHeight feature appears to not do anything for any value.

```
function formDialog1() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form HTML 1');
  html.setWidth(20);
  html.setHeight(20);
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Opening...');
}
```

Form HTML 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
          test
  </body>
</html>
```

Size of Dialog Box:

[image: Dialog Box]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Creating a new HtmlOutput object from existing HtmlOutput object on which height and width was set.

#### Solution:

- Use the original HtmlOutput in the ui interface.

#### Snippet:

```
function formDialog1() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form HTML 1');
  html.setWidth(20);
  html.setHeight(20);
  //var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Opening...');//modified
}
```